# jQuery variable (select in html)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new in Jquery, and I have this code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        var title = jQuery(".fullVisaImg").attr("inselect");

        var links = jQuery(".ff_elem>option");

        for(var i=0; i<links.length; i++) {
            if (title == links[i].value) {
                links[i].attr("selected", "selected"); // here is my problem
                alert(links[i].value);
                return;
            }
        }
    });
```

i have a `select` element on my pages, and want to make one of elements selected. if I comment line with `// here...` all works good, and i see all my `option` values.

Thanks for help!

Comment: If you just need 1 element selected then why are you looping over all the options and marking them as selected. Why not use html attribute `selected` in your markup?

Comment: i hope it's not because of missing closing quote; anyway, why not use `.val()`?

Comment: this `select` element making with php, i can't change it.

Comment: `links.eq(i).prop("selected", true);` ???

Comment: `links.eq(i).attr("selected", "selected");` Thanks  A. Wolff !

Comment: which jquery version you are using??

Comment: @AndrewEvt As for jquery 1.6, `.prop()` is preferred method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following your code, you could use:

```
links.eq(i).prop("selected", true);
```

Comment: My guess is you have zero explanation about the reason for the error unlike the one right below that explained the error.

Comment: @epascarello ya, sorry about that!

Answer (score 2):

When you use `[]` to access an element in a jquery set, you get back the raw DOM element. So you can not use jquery methods on it directly..

You should also use `.prop` instead of `.attr()` when interacting with properties of the element

So use

```
links.eq(i).prop("selected", true);
```

Answer (score 2):

replace you for loop with:

```
jQuery(".ff_elem").val(title);
```

I have created this [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nEcd5/) for you. Check it out.

Although You can iterate through all your option elements and find your option element, and then do this:

```
links[i].prop("selected", true);
```

but there is no need to iterate when you can simply let your select element do this for you as I have mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually how you can select an option based on the value your options have.

```
$('select').val('value of the option you want to select');
```

so use

```
$(".ff_elem").val(title);
```

Comment: He's looking for a working solution to `links[i].attr("selected", "selected");`

Comment: Why do you keep editing it and breaking the correct way to mark up code?

Comment: @epascarello Sorry, i didn't even get why you would add 4 spaces to my answer, probably because i forgot them...

Answer (score 0):

if your jquery version is above 1.6+ then use this

```
links.eq(i).prop("selected", true);
```

else

```
   links.eq(i).attr("selected", "selected");
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be much simpler. Try something like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    var title = jQuery(".fullVisaImg").attr("inselect");

    jQuery(".ff_elem>option[value=" + title + "]").attr("selected", "selected");
});
```

Comment: Should be prop() with modern versions of jQuery

Comment: This is far from simple, as it can be done simpler with jQuery.

Comment: It is still simpler than running a for loop to find 'title'.

Answer (score -2):

links is a jQuery collection.  When you loop through it, you're just getting the raw element, not a jQuery wrapped version, so you can't use .attr().

Use this instead at your problem line.

```
$(links[i]).attr("selected", "selected");
```